# High-Powered USB hub with no AC adapter driven by 2 USB inputs

Tags: usb, power

Is there any USB hub that is powered like some of the USB hard drives (connected to 2 ports at the same time). I want to avoid using AC adapter and use two USB ports to power a hub.
Does anybody know any examples of such devices?

Comment: Do you mean, you want it powered by a Molex cable or some such?

Comment: I was thinking about double usb cable, something like http://www.lindy.co.uk/lindyshop/pictures/31784big.jpg

Comment: I have a USB hard drive that has a cable like this (one end single, one end double). The cable can be used for other devices, but I never used it, and never understood what it was useful for... I'm curious what you would use it for.

Comment: yeah, that's actually it, but I was thinking about something that offers more outputs like: http://www.amazon.com/D-Link-DUB-H7-High-Speed-7-Port/dp/B00008VFAF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003DA5U0E/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00 (see all pictures)

Comment: if anybody has different examples with more usb outputs without the card readers etc. please post, thanks.